# YAML sequence indicator (-) but with mapped value and no "child elements"

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, yaml

How does one create the following YAML content from an Java Object? I use Jackson Yaml and I want to create such a YAML file.

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: sampleName  //how to create this line, what does it mean? it is no sequence right?
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  scrape_interval: 10s
  metrics_path: samplePath
  file_sd_configs:   //works with List in List from the Java Object
    - files:
      - sampleFile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- attribute: value
  attribute2: value
```

is equivalent of

```
-
   attribute:value
   attribute2: value
```

So it is a List containing an object.

In case of doubt convert it to JSON with an online converter.
The JSON result is:

```
{
   "scrape_configs": [
      {
         "job_name": "sampleName",
         "scrape_timeout": "10s",
         "scrape_interval": "10s",
         "metrics_path": "samplePath",
         "file_sd_configs": [
            {
               "files": [
                  "sampleFile"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Note:
example of convertion tool : https://www.json2yaml.com/

Comment: works now thank you...
I just created a list of config and wrote them to YAML